# Using Fourier Transforms to Solve Heat Equation (3-D)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, heat-equation

I was wondering how you would go about using Fourier Transforms to solve a heat equation that has an extra dimension like:

$u_t = k(u_{xx} + u_{yy})$

From what I understand, if you had just the 2-D heat equation $u_t = u_{xx}$ , you would take that:

$\mathfrak{F}(u(x,t) = U(w,t)$, and then

$\mathfrak{F}({\frac{\partial^n u}{\partial t^n}}) = \frac{d^n U}{dt^n}$, and   $\mathfrak{F}({\frac{\partial^n u}{\partial x^n}}) = (iw)^nU(w,t)$

And simply substitute. But how do you deal with this $u_{yy}$ term? What is $\mathfrak{F}({\frac{\partial^n u}{\partial y^n}})$ equal to?

Note: This is from a university intro to partial differential equations course. My understanding of PDE's is pretty basic.

Comment: Have you learned about the Fourier transform in 2 variables?

Comment: We have mostly focused on transforms of the form $u_t = u_{xx}$ and we have done a few questions regarding Laplace's equation in 2 dimensions

Comment: Would I just substitute in $\mathfrak{F}({\frac{\partial^n u}{\partial y^n}}) = (ij)^nU(w,t)$ ? Or any random letter instead of j

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In higher dimension, just replace products by scalar products, that is if $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and $w = (w_1,w_2)$, then $x\cdot w = x_1w_1 + x_2w_2$, your equation is
$$
\partial_t u = k\left(\partial_{x_1x_1}u + \partial_{x_2x_2}u\right) = k \,\nabla\cdot\nabla u,
$$
and the Fourier transform is
$$
U(w)={\mathcal F}(u)(w) = \iint_{\Bbb R^2} e^{-ix\cdot w} \, u(x)\,\mathrm d x
$$
So that
$$
\partial_t U(w) = k\,iw\cdot iw \,U(w) = - k\,|w|^2 \,U(w)
$$